# Is there away to send Json Data from a form with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I want to send Json data from my model variable that has all my form bindings. When I use postman the requests go through but when I do it in angular it doesn't work. I have no idea what I am doing so that it doesn't send my post request properly but I can't get it to format correctly.I keep on getting a observable when I console.log my request. I tried everything but it's not working.I think angular is adding the keyword "new" to my response body.This is a link to **my live code:** [live](https://stackblitz.com/github/RashellSmith/Dashboard-FrontEnd/tree/Weekend-Changes)
 I get this error with my spring boot application:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Oct 06 12:26:12 EDT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "new"
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "new"
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "new"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:402)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:53)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:693)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:124)
    ... 51 more
```

home.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Newproduct } from '../model/Newproduct';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'Transfer-Encoding':'chunked',

  })
};
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
// @ts-ignore
export class HomeService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/product');
  }
  getByPriceAsc():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/product/price/up');
  }
  getByPriceDesc():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/product/price/down');
  }
  getBySaleAsc():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/product/sale/up');
  }
  getBySaleDesc():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/product/sale/down');
  }

  getByDiscountAsc():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/product/discount/up');
  }
  getByDiscountDesc():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/product/discount/down');
  }

  getByParm(availability,category):Observable<any>{

    return this.http.get( 'http://localhost:8080/api/'+'product/category/'+ availability +'/'+ category);


  }


  addProduct(model:any):Observable<any>{
    console.log( this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/product/new',model,httpOptions));
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/product/new',model,httpOptions);
  }



}
```

product-form.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../model/Product';
import { Category } from '../model/Category';
import { Supplier } from '../model/Supplier';
import { SupplierService } from '../service/Supplier.service';
import { CategoryService } from '../service/Category.service';
import { Newproduct } from '../model/Newproduct';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Home } from '../model/Home';
import { HomeService } from '../service/Home.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

suppliers: Supplier[];
categories: Category[];
value: number;
model = { productName: '', category: {category: null, categoryName: null}, fullPrice: '', salePrice:'', availability: false, supplier: {supplier:null,supplierName:null}, 
discount:null };

json = JSON.stringify(this.model);

// model = new Newproduct(null,new Category( this.value,"name"),null,null,false,new Supplier(null,null),null);
GetSelectedValue(change){
  console.log(change);
}
GetSelectedValue1(change){
  console.log(change);
}
submitted = false;
get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.model)};



onSubmit() { 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model));
  this.homeService.addProduct(this.model);
 }

  constructor(private supplierService: SupplierService,private categoryService: CategoryService,private homeService: HomeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.supplierService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.suppliers = data;
    });




    this.categoryService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
      this.categories = data;
    });
  }
}
```

I tried everything I possibly could think of switching forms structure. json.strinify to get my code to json format.  it works perfectly in postman so I think that it's a problem with my httpclient and how I am structuring the post request.

Comment: From the top line of your Java error, somewhere Angular is sending a string where an integer is expected. What _exactly_ is being sent and what _should_ be sent?

Comment: Debug what is been sended through post man by checking the network tab in Chrome and aslso check the network request your service make in your local project both should match